# Is it possible to make a Fan chart with CSS?

Tags: css

I'm wondering if it is possible to make a fan chart like the one below but only using HTML/CSS. I've been trying to use transforms and nested divs but nothing has come even remotely close.

[image]

Comment: No, it would not be possible. You could achieve this in something like D3, here is an example http://www.jasondavies.com/coffee-wheel/

Comment: D3's responsability is only to manage the data. The proper tool to render such display is `svg`. Then this could be static, or dynamic using D3, angular, jquery, vanillaJS etc.

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger You mean D3 can take svg as input and modify how it would appear?

Comment: Nope. D3 is only responsible for managing the data: checking when some data changes and decide whether a redraw is necessary. Pretty much like Angular does. But the build-the-svg-logic has to be built by you, from an example or not. Eg. to make a square you'll need `function(center, side){ return 'M '+center.x+' '+center.y+', m '+side+' 0, m (etc.)'; }`

Comment: But the good thing with D3 still is that it offers plenty of examples of JS -> SVG functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the canvas. Just getting rotating text to work with css is a pain in the ass. I could imagine doing the text alone from your image above, but it would take so much work to implement. The shapes and lines is a whole other story. I imagine it's probably possible, but it probably wouldn't look good, and probably would be inefficient. The canvas is the way to go here.